# Add same product multiple time without quantity in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, woothemes

I am doing customization in woocommerce plugins of wordpress. I need to display any product multiple time without quantity. Suppose we clicked add to cart for product 'Chair'. It would be add two individual time in cart not a one product 'Chair' with quantity 2.

By default woocommerce display the following manner.
Chairx2 = $20

I am doing customization for this type of outputs
Chair = $10
 
Chair = $10

I have done this code.

```
function wc_remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {
    return true;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'wc_remove_all_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Add this to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to give each item in the cart a `unique_key` like this:

```
function add_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item_key ) { 
    $cart_item_data[custom_data]['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() ); 
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
```

Just paste that code on your functions.php file and it's done!